# How can I pass a texture to a custom deferred lighting model in Unity?

Tags: shaders, unity

I've replaced the `Internal-DeferredShading.shader` with my own shader, and it's working fine, but I want to add a uniform texture for it to sample from.

I've tried adding a texture as a property and assigning it a default value in the inspector but at run-time the shader still uses the default value given in the shader (e.g. `white`).

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Not 5 minutes after posting this I found a solution. Might as well share it here if someone else is curious about this in the future.)

It's possible to set the texture using [Shader.SetGlobalTexture](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Shader.SetGlobalTexture.html). For this to work properly I also had to remove the texture as a property of the shader.

I have the following script attached to an object in the scene and it's working perfectly:

```
[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class ChangeDeferredLightingTexture : MonoBehaviour {

    public Texture texture;
    public string shaderVariableName;

    void OnValidate() {
        Shader.SetGlobalTexture(shaderVariableName, texture);
    }
}
```